# 3 Way Binding in Angular & Firebase causing lag in input boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am binding a users profile data to a variable like this:

```
// Profile Management
var user = firebase.child('users').child(userID);
$firebaseObject(user).$bindTo($scope, 'user');
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-show="firebaseUser">
    <h1>Your Profile</h1>

    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="profilePicture">
            <img src="images/noProfile.png">
        </div>
        <div class="personalInfo">

            <input type="text" ng-model="user.Name" ng-change="user.$save()" type="text" 
                   label="Name" placeholder="Your Name.." name="userName">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.Phone" ng-change="user.$save()" type="text" 
                   label="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone #.." name="userPhone">

            <label>Email</label>
            {{firebaseUser.password.email}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's working, when I type into the profile, it automatically updates the Firebase database, however there is severe lag, it's extremely noticeable if you type to fast a lot of words get skipped, this happens so much that it's un-usable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User this. `ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500} }` the scope cycle gonna be triggered will delay by 500ms. You can also adjust it to fit with the usage of the app. Cheer!

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.Name" ng-change="user.$save()" type="text" 
    ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500} }"   
    label="Name" placeholder="Your Name.." name="userName">

    <input type="text" ng-model="user.Phone" ng-change="user.$save()" type="text" 
    ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500} }"
    label="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone #.." name="userPhone">
```

Comment: Works incredibly! Thanks!!